# subtract java text string

Tags: java, split, substring, indexof

I want to extract the reference from an URL.

For example, my URL looks like:

```
"https://www.amazon.es/Lenovo-YOGA-520-14IKB-Ordenador-convertible/dp/B071WBF4PZ/"
```

I want to get only the reference part, that is **B071WBF4PZ**

I also want to extract the price from this html element:

```
"<div id="cerberus-data-metrics" style="display: none;" data-asin="B078ZYX4R5" data-asin-price="1479.00" data-asin-shipping="0" data-asin-currency-code="EUR" data-substitute-count="0" data-device-type="WEB" data-display-code="Asin is not eligible because it has a retail offer" ></div>"
```

I need to get only the value of the attribute **data-asin-price**.

It could be done with `indexOf',`substring`or`split` but I don't get how to do it.

Comment: The two examples are completely different: how can a computer know how get the information you want? (do you want the last piece of the URL or the part between some tags, or something else?)

Comment: the examples are from a page, from the URL I want the last part that is the reference B071WBF4PZ is between '/' and from the second part only what is between quotes of data-asin-price = "1479.00", would be the price 1479.00

Thank you

Comment: Is your problem **really** parsing the string, or what is your context? E.g. if you use Spring, this parsing is solved for you completely automagically by Spring.

Comment: As with Spring??

Comment: Are you trying to scrape data from an `HTML` page?

Comment: Yes mark, I download the URL with java, I save it in a txt file, and from there I want to subtract what I ask, both the reference of the URL that is in /, and the price of the div

Comment: use jsoup library  https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

Answer (score 3):

- Reference part:

code:

```
String url = "https://www.amazon.es/Lenovo-YOGA-520-14IKB-Ordenador-convertible/dp/B071WBF4PZ/";

String[] parts = string.split("/");
// parts : 
// [0] = "https:"
// [1] = ""
// [2] =  "www.amazon.es"
// [3] = "Lenovo-YOGA-520-14IKB-Ordenador-convertible"
// [4] = "dp"
// [5] = "B071WBF4PZ"
// [6] = ""

String reference = parts[5]; // < this is the reference.
```

However, I would recommend using [Regular Expressions / patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

And also check if `parts.length() >= 6` before you access `[5]`

- Price part:

Using [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) you can easily parse html and extract properties like `data-asin-price`. In this case I would not use Regular Expressions. However Regular expressions don't need extra libraries.

This RegEx:

```
(?:data-asin-price=")(\w*.\w*)
```

will match any number after `data-asin-price="` - so the match group 1 will be: `1479.00`

Comment: and doing it with an index of can not be counted from position 17 is when the price starts