# subtract part of text

Tags: java, split, substring, indexof

I have this code

```
public void descargarURL() {
    try{
        URL url = new URL("https://www.amazon.es/MSI-Titan-GT73EVR-7RD-1027XES-Ordenador/dp/B078ZYX4R5/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1524239679&sr=8-1");
        BufferedReader lectura = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        File archivo = new File("descarga2.txt");
        BufferedWriter escritura = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(archivo));
        BufferedWriter ficheroNuevo = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("nuevoFichero.txt"));
        String texto;

        while ((texto = lectura.readLine()) != null) {
            escritura.write(texto);

            }
        lectura.close();
        escritura.close();
        ficheroNuevo.close();
        System.out.println("Archivo creado!");
        //}

    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Paginaweb2 pg = new Paginaweb2();
    pg.descargarURL();
}
```

}

And I want to remove from the URL the part of the reference that is **B078ZYX4R5**, and this entity /

After the html that is saved in the text file there is a part of the code that has `*"<div id =" cerberus-data-metrics "style =" display: none; "data-asin =" B078ZYX4R5 "data-as-price = "1479.00" data-asin-shipping = "0" data-asin-currency-code = "EUR" data-substitute-count = "0" data-device-type = "WEB" data-display-code = "Asin is not eligible because it has a retail offer "> </ div>"*`, and I want to only get the price from there that is **1479.00**, it is included among the tags **"data-as-price = "**

I dont want to use external libraries, I know that it can be done with split, index of, and substring

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [subtract java text string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50016760/subtract-java-text-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve both tasks by using regular expressions. Yet for the second task (extraction of the price from the HTML) you could use [JSOUP](https://jsoup.org/) which is much better suited to extract content from HTML.

Here are some possible solutions based on regular expressions for your tasks:

### 1. Change URL

```
private static String modifyUrl(String str) {
    return str.replaceFirst("/[^/]+(?=/ref)", "");
}
```

This is just a replacement using a regular expression using a positive look-ahead `(?=/ref)` (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

### Extract Price

```
private static Optional<String> extractPrice(String html) {
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("data-as-price\\s*=\\s*[\"'](?<price>.+?)[\"']", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(html);
    if(m.find()) {
        String price = m.group("price");
        return Optional.of(price);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Here you can use also a regular expression (`data-as-price\s*=\s*["'](?<price>.+?)["']`) to locate the price. With a named group (`(?<price>.+?)`) you can then extract the price.

I am returning an `Optional` here so that you can deal with the case that the price was not found.

Here is a simple test case for the two methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String str = "https://www.amazon.es/MSI-Titan-GT73EVR-7RD-1027XES-Ordenador/dp/B078ZYX4R5/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1524239679&sr=8-1";
    System.out.println(modifyUrl(str));
    String html = "<div id =\" cerberus-data-metrics \"style =\" display: none; \"data-asin =\" B078ZYX4R5 \"data-as-price = \"1479.00\" data-asin-shipping = \"0\" data-asin-currency-code = \"EUR\" data-substitute-count = \"0\" data-device-type = \"WEB\" data-display-code = \"Asin is not eligible because it has a retail offer \"> </ div>";
    extractPrice(html).ifPresent(System.out::println);
}
```

If you run this simple test case you will see on the console this output:

```
https://www.amazon.es/MSI-Titan-GT73EVR-7RD-1027XES-Ordenador/dp/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1524239679&sr=8-1
1479.00
```

### Update

If you want to extract the reference from the URL, you can do it using similar code to the one used to extract the price. Here is a method which extract a specific named group from a pattern:

```
private static Optional<String> extractNamedGroup(String str, Pattern pat, String reference) {
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(str);
    if (m.find()) {
        return Optional.of(m.group(reference));
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Then you can use this method for extracting the reference and price:

```
private static Optional<String> extractReference(String str) {
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("/(?<reference>[^/]+)(?=/ref)");
    return extractNamedGroup(str, pat, "reference");
}

private static Optional<String> extractPrice(String html) {
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("data-as-price\\s*=\\s*[\"'](?<price>.+?)[\"']", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    return extractNamedGroup(html, pat, "price");
}
```

You can test the above methods with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String str = "https://www.amazon.es/MSI-Titan-GT73EVR-7RD-1027XES-Ordenador/dp/B078ZYX4R5/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1524239679&sr=8-1";
    extractReference(str).ifPresent(System.out::println);
    String html = "<div id =\" cerberus-data-metrics \"style =\" display: none; \"data-asin =\" B078ZYX4R5 \"data-as-price = \"1479.00\" data-asin-shipping = \"0\" data-asin-currency-code = \"EUR\" data-substitute-count = \"0\" data-device-type = \"WEB\" data-display-code = \"Asin is not eligible because it has a retail offer \"> </ div>";
    extractPrice(html).ifPresent(System.out::println);
}
```

This will print:

```
B078ZYX4R5
1479.00
```

#### Update 2: Using URL

If you want to use the `java.net.URL` class to help you narrow down the search scope you can do it. But you cannot use this class to do the full extraction.
Since the token you want to extract is in the URL path you can extract the path and then apply the regular expression explained above to do the extraction.

Here is the sample code you can use to narrow down the search scope:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String str = "https://www.amazon.es/MSI-Titan-GT73EVR-7RD-1027XES-Ordenador/dp/B078ZYX4R5/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1524239679&sr=8-1";
    URL url = new URL(str); 
    extractReference(url.getPath() /* narrowing the search scope here */).ifPresent(System.out::println);
    String html = "<div id =\" cerberus-data-metrics \"style =\" display: none; \"data-asin =\" B078ZYX4R5 \"data-as-price = \"1479.00\" data-asin-shipping = \"0\" data-asin-currency-code = \"EUR\" data-substitute-count = \"0\" data-device-type = \"WEB\" data-display-code = \"Asin is not eligible because it has a retail offer \"> </ div>";
    extractPrice(html).ifPresent(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Fantastic and many thanks, but would not there be another way to pass the URL to String without setting it to default?

Then in what comes out by console, the price is great, but the URL, I want only the reference that is B078ZYX4R5

Thank you very much!

Comment: @Ashe Please check the updated answer which contains a method for extracting the reference.

Comment: but would not there be another way to pass the URL to String without setting it to default?

Comment: @Ashe I actually do not have an 100% understanding of what you mean with "another way to pass the URL to String without setting it to default". I assume you want to use the methods of the java.net.URL class to perform some sort of extraction instead of using the plain input string. Please confirm if my assumption is correct.

Comment: Exactly, I want to use the methods of the URL class, so when doing the function function, you will not leave me, suggestion?

Comment: @Ashe you can narrow down the scope for extraction with the `java.net.URL` class. See the latest update of the answer with an explanation above.

Comment: What¿?  , You have taken the url as a string,

Comment: @Ashe I have used this code to extract the path: `url.getPath()`. This extracts in the case above: '/MSI-Titan-GT73EVR-7RD-1027XES-Ordenador/dp/B078ZYX4R5/ref=sr_1_1'. And then from this path I use the regular expression to do the final extraction. The `java.net.URL` does not have the facilities to extract `B078ZYX4R5`. But it can help to shorten the string in which you search.

Comment: @Ashe If this answer was helpful, consider accepting it.